# Message with array of data

Tags: ros, message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I try to create a custom message containing an array of int8. Therefore I use the .msg-file

```
int8 len
int8[] data
```

and when I run colcon everything is fine. The resulting node publishes messages as shown above. When I run the node it immediately crashes without any warnings or errors. The node itself works fine when I use sensor_msgs::msg::Imu. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Regards
s0nc

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/397658/message-with-array-of-data/) by [s0nc](https://answers.ros.org/users/88613/s0nc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2022-03-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-03-20**:
Just to be sure - did you add this new message to your CMakeLists in `rosidl_generate_interfaces(${PROJECT_NAME} ...)` and `rosidl_default_generators`,  `rosidl_default_runtime` int the `package.xml` in build and exec dependencies?

**Comment by [s0nc](https://answers.ros.org/users/88613/s0nc/) on 2022-03-21**:
I just included them as build_depend. It finally works. Thank you!

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-03-21**:
Awesome, I just copied my comment to the answer, please upvote and accept it so your question will be marked as solved :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just to be sure - you have to add this new message to your CMakeLists.txt in `rosidl_generate_interfaces(${PROJECT_NAME} ...)` and `rosidl_default_generators`, `rosidl_default_runtime` in the `package.xml` in build and exec dependencies.

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2022-03-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3